# Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.myfaces.custom.aliasbean.AliasBeanTagHandler.<init>(javax.faces.view.facelets.ComponentConfig)

Tags: jsf

I have recently upgraded my project to richfaces 4 from richfaces3 and also JSF 1 is been upgraded to JSF 2. I find no issues during the build and build is successful. But when I am trying to deploy application using JBOSS 6 I get below error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.myfaces.custom.aliasbean.AliasBeanTagHandler.<init>(javax.faces.view.facelets.ComponentConfig)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2892) [:1.7.0_72]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1723) [:1.7.0_72]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.AbstractTagLibrary$UserComponentHandlerFactory.<init>(AbstractTagLibrary.java:290) [:2.0.3-]
    ... 93 more
```

I have tried a lots of things but nothing worked. Any kinda help would be much appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Problem suggests that you've still MyFaces 1.x or Tomahawk for JSF 1.x bundled in your webapp.

Comment: Hi BalusC Thanks a lot the problem is resolved. Yes I was still having Tomahawk for JSF 1.x. Thanks a lot again :)...